# Can I ask questions about typesetters that are not strictly variants of TeX in tex.se?

Tags: discussion

Can users ask questions regarding WYSIWYM typesetters that bear similarities to TeX? For example, [SILE](https://sile-typesetter.org/) owes a lot of its syntax from TeX.

Comment: Sile seems to have a Q&A section at https://github.com/sile-typesetter/sile/discussions/categories/q-a I think your chances to get the eyes of a sile user on your question would be better there.

Answer (score 17):

I think that that it would be very confusing to ask sile specific questions (and in general a bad place to ask if you want to have it answered by people knowledgeable about sile). Of course questions asking for comparisons between the two may still be on topic.  Mathjax for example is (for math at least) much closer to tex than sile but is generally considered off topic.